# How to disable temporarily events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to do a security on a page where the user have to click on save buttons.
So when the user click on the good section there no problems but if he does modifications and click in the other section (navbar) a confirm appear to say him that he didn't save.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".col-md-12");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 )
    {
        if (sessionStorage['Sort'])
        {
            var r = confirm("Disposition non sauvegardée ! Continuer ?");        
        }
    }
});
```

I use sessionStorage to an other function and fill it if the user does modifications, in the aim to use this in the "if".

It works fine for that, but if the user click on a category in the navbar, the confirm appear and if he clicks on "cancel" he goes in the category.

That's why i want to disable events while the confirme is here. If he clicks on cancel, the user must stay on the same page.
Have you an idea to disable all the others event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) function?

> An event that fires when a window is about to unload its resources. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

An example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
   if (unsavedChanges) return 'Dialog text here.'; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dialog box to prevent user action while the process is working.

Here is a sample of this

The HTML part

```
<div 
    id="waitScreen" 
    style="background-color:black;
           color:white;
           font-weight:bold;
           font-size:1.5em;
           border: 5px solid red;">
     Processing Request, please wait...
 </div>
```

The jQuery part

```
var modalWait = $("#waitScreen").dialog({
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    dialogClass: 'no-title'
 });

 $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

Then you can close it after the processing is completed.

```
modalWait.dialog("close");
```

Comment: it's not really that i need, Actually it's for the case "if the user forgot to save" the confirm appear and say him that he hasn't save. but if the user click directly on another category in the navbar and he doest'n save if he clicks ok or cancel in the confirm he's redirected. And i need when he clicks on cancel to stay on the same page